# How to add custom validator in validation.xml

Tags: regex, xml, validation

I'm trying to add custom validator by using validation.xml because I want to use two or more regular expression(mask).I added validator name as mask1 in validator-rule.

```
<validator name="mask"
        classname="org.apache.struts.validator.FieldChecks" method="validateMask"
        methodParams="java.lang.Object,
                   org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction,
                   org.apache.commons.validator.Field,
                   org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages,
                   org.apache.commons.validator.Validator,
                   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest"
        depends="" msg="AZ0022" />


    <validator name="mask1"
        classname="org.apache.struts.validator.FieldChecks" method="validateMask"
        methodParams="java.lang.Object,
                   org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction,
                   org.apache.commons.validator.Field,
                   org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages,
                   org.apache.commons.validator.Validator,
                   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest"
        depends="" msg="AZ0022" />
```

And, I used mask and mask1 in my validation.xml.

```
<form name="testForm">
<field property="testField" depends="mask,mask1">
        <msg  key="msg1120 name="mask"/>
        <msg key="msg1121" name="mask1" />        
        <arg key="testField"/>
        <var>
              <var-name>mask</var-name>
              <var-value>
    ^(?:[！＃＄（）＊＋－．／０-９：＝？)*$
    </var-value>
        </var>      
        <var>
              <var-name>mask1</var-name>
              <var-value>^[^ ]</var-value>
        </var>              
    </field>
</form>
```

But, now only appear the error message of mask in my project. How to add custom validator in validation.xml. Thank you!

Comment: Your character class is not closed, use `^[！＃＄（）＊＋．／０-９：＝？－]*$`.

Comment: @stribizhev ⇒　No, character class is sample. It is not important.Mainly is to add custom validator in validation!

Comment: Then I guess you need to remove regex tag and add another one relevant for your issue.